# Update User interface when a button is pressed Tkinter

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

So basically i want the user interface to be updated when a user presses the start button, however when i call the maininit function it returns an error saying that root is not defined, is there any way i can get around this?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH,W, N, E, S, Entry, Text, INSERT, Toplevel
from ttk import Frame, Style, Button, Label
import Tkinter
import Callingwordlist

class MainGameUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Type!")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        style = Style()
        style.configure("TFrame", background="black")

        Type = Image.open("Type!.png")
        Typet = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Type)
        label3 = Label(self, image=Typet)
        label3.image = Typet
        label3.place(x=0, y=0)


        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        MenuButton = Button(self, text="Main Menu")
        MenuButton.pack()
        MenuButton.place(x=560,y=20,height = 80,width = 100)

        QuitButton = Button(self,text="Quit",command=self.parent.destroy)
        QuitButton.pack()
        QuitButton.place(x=680,y=20,height = 80,width = 100)

        StartButton = Button(self, text="Start",command=maininit)
        StartButton.pack()
        StartButton.place(x=440,y=20,height=80,width=100)

def maininit():

    entry1 = Entry(root,font =("Courier",38), width = 22)
    entry1.pack(ipady=10)
    entry1.config(bg="#CEF6F5")
    entry1.place(x=90,y=200)

    entry2 = Entry(root,font =("Courier",38), width = 22)
    entry2.pack(ipady=10)
    entry2.config(bg="#CEF6F5")
    entry2.place(x=90,y=350)

    text1 = Text(root,width=23,height=1,font=("Courier",38))
    text1.pack()
    text1.config(bg="black",fg="white",bd=0)
    text1.place(x=90,y=150)
    text1.insert(INSERT,"Hello")

    text2 = Text(root,width=23,height=1,font=("Courier",38))
    text2.pack()
    text2.config(bg="black",fg="white",bd=0)
    text2.place(x=90,y=300)
    text2.insert(INSERT,"Test")

    dtext = Text(root,font=("Courier",28),width=10,height=1)
    dtext.pack()
    dtext.config(bg="black",fg="white",bd=0)
    dtext.insert(INSERT,"Difficulty")
    dtext.place(x=90,y=500)

    atext = Text(root,font=("Courier",28),width=8,height=1)
    atext.pack()
    atext.config(bg="black",fg="white",bd=0)
    atext.insert(INSERT,"Accuracy")
    atext.place(x=595,y=500)

    dentry = Text(root,font=("Courier",28),width=1,height=1)
    dentry.pack()
    dentry.config(bg="white",bd=0)
    dentry.place(x=180,y=550)
    dentry.insert(INSERT,"Test")

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("860x640+300+300")
    app = MainGameUI(root) 
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, `root` is a locally defined variable confined to `main()`. You need to somehow pass `root` as an argument to `maininit`. Here is one way to do this:

First, change `maininit()` so that it accepts a parameter `root`:

```
def maininit(root):
    ...
```

Now, change the callback on `StartButton` so it passes `maininit()` the `root` object:

```
class MainGameUI(Frame):
    ...
    def initUI(self):
        ...
        StartButton = Button(self, text="Start",command=lambda: maininit(self.parent))
        ...
```

Comment: That worked a charm, thanks for the nice quick response

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `root` inside a function, whose calling namespace is not available to the `maininit()` function. If you omit the definition of `main()` and instead write

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("860x640+300+300")
    app = MainGameUI(root) 
    root.mainloop()
```

`root` will then be defined in the global module namespace, where it IS available to the code in the function.